# How do I place a text on the north west of an circle using tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here is a simple full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\section{}

\begin{figure}
    \newcommand\radius{2}
    \newcommand\spacing{2}
    
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (-\radius-\spacing/2, 0) circle (\radius);
        \draw (\radius+\spacing/2, 0) circle (\radius) node[anchor = north west]{Test};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
```

The output is

[image]

But what I want is that the "Test" text is on the north west of the circle *border*. It seems like I'm anchoring on the north west of the circle *center* instead. How can I fix that?

Comment: If you‘d use a NODE with shape circle, that would work. However, this circle is just some path. So use sth like \node at (135:2){Text};

Comment: `node[anchor=north west]` means that the north west corner of the node ("Test") is placed at the coordinate (the circle centrum).

Answer (score 2):

With `\draw (<x>,<y>) circle[radius=<r>] node[anchor=north west] {Test};`, the node is placed at the point `(<x>,<y>)`. A solution is to place the node separately at the point `({3+2*cos(135)},{2*sin(135)})`.

According to the pgfmanual, the syntax `\draw (3,0) circle (2);` is old. The newer syntax is `\draw (3,0) circle[radius=2];`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-3,0) circle[radius=2];
\draw (3,0) circle[radius=2];
\fill ({3+2*cos(135)},{2*sin(135)}) circle[radius=2pt];
\node[anchor=north west] at ({3+2*cos(135)},{2*sin(135)}) {Test};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want, but you can add a `label` to a node at any angle:

[image]

You can adjust the label distance using positive or negative lengths:

`label={[label distance=2mm]135:Test}`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, circle, minimum size=4cm, label=135:Test]{};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```